# Change Text Font In Eclipse For GWT Text Editors

Tags: eclipse, gwt, fonts

I am using Eclipse with the GWT Eclipse Plugin. I want to use a different font than the default (in this case, Fira Code). In my preferences, in Colors and Fonts, I set the setting "Text Font" to use Fira Code and it works perfectly fine in normal Java text editors. However, if I open a source file that is in a GWT project, the GWT Eclipse Plugin uses its own text editor that ignores the custom font and uses Eclipse's default instead.

Is there a way to force the GWT text editor to use that setting too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no official fix yet, GitHub user voytechs provides a work-around [here](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/389):

> Unless you absolutely need to use the GWT Java Editor for every single .java file type because it has syntax support for JNSI code, you can change the order in which the text editors are chosen for the .java file type.
>
> Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations > File Types > *.java > Associated editors:
>
> - Select "Java Editor"
> - Click "Default" button to make that the default editor
>
> You can still edit java files with JNSI comment code in it with the GWT Java Editor:
>
> - Project Explorer > Right Click your .java" file > Open With > GWT Java Editor
>
> The regular java editor can easily change the default font size or resize the font size on the fly. I adjust the font size using the ctrl+ and ctrl- key press inside the Java editor.